Where is the origin of coordinates in tikz
I am trying to create an equilateral triangle on my paper using LaTeX, but I do not understand how tikz (or tikzpicture) choose where is the origin (0,0) of its coordinates.
After writing a text, I want to draw my triangle on the right side of my paper with the following code:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%parameters are the following : cooX , cooY , triangleSize
\newcommand{\triangle} [3] {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (#1,#2)--(#1+0.5*#3,#2+0.86*#3)--(#1+1*#3,#2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\normalsize
Here is my text and the triangle
\triangle {10}{0}{3}
\end{document}

This creates:

My goal is to draw the triangle 10cm to the right, by calling the function \triangle with on first parameter {10}. As you can see on my code, I want the first point of the triangle to be drawn on my already chosen coordinates (10,0) which are the parameters of my newcommand \triangle. The problem is that the origin is always the same, no matter what I do to my parameters. The result will be the same if I put {20} instead of {10}, and I want it to be shifted to the right by 10 or 20cm depending on my parameters. On the other hand, if I change a parameter with a number which is not the one I chose when I call my newcommand like this :
...
\draw (20,#2)--(#1+0.5*#3,#2+0.86*#3)--(#1+1*#3,#2)--cycle;
...
\triangle {10}{0}{3}
...

(I changed on this code the first #1 with a 20, replacing 10 by 20).
Then tikz takes into account this change and shows me a deformed triangle, with a starting point on the very right:

It's like if tikz always wants to put the origin at the same place, no matter what constant (#1 and #2) I add to my coordinates.
What do I have to do in order to move my triangle according to the parameters I give to my newcommand \triangle ?

Welcome to TeX.SX!. The dimensions of the result of a tikz drawing depends on its contents. Usually, tikz tries to find a rectangle that includes everything. To include whitespace (or arcs that go outside) you can use \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (12,1) or create some invisible nodes, that are considered by tikz for the arranging.

Welcome. // Though your question is understandable, it's the wrong perspective. See my answer (in a minute or two).

How about this ? \hspace*{5cm}\triangle {10}{0}{3}

There are some aspects you should be aware of, in no particular order. First let's see the screenshot of the code below.

(1) The white triangles are from your macro, with some differences in the code itself. There's the convention that a newline (really a blank line) typed creates a new line type-set.
(2) LaTeX is typesetting, not typewriting, as you may know from Word or other editors. It tries to typeset entities. In your case these are:

individual characters, including space
something a \newcommand created (white triangle)
and can be many more

Think of a box around each letter, or triangle, created in lead like in the old times of Gutenberg or you past local newspaper.
LaTeX will continue to glue entity by entity together, until it finishes, trying to realize what it "knows" to be "a nice typeset result".
(3) It's a well-known effect that the last character of each line inside a \newcommand should end with a % (i.e. commenting the rest of the line out). If you miss it, LaTeX tries to typeset spaces you didn't intend (simplified).
(4) My two variations of your triangle, teal and yellow, differ this way:

teal has a horizontal space (your sought shift) of 7cm (with 10cm the difference wouldn't be visible enough) via \hspace{}
yellow uses \hfill instead: It shifts the "block" to its outmost right here.

(5) Kindly recognize my European choice in the \documentclass ;-)
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%parameters are the following : cooX , cooY , triangleSize
\newcommand{\trngl}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw (#1,#2)--(#1+0.5*#3,#2+0.86*#3)--(#1+1*#3,#2)--cycle;%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\trnglA}[3]{%
\hspace{7cm}\begin{tikzpicture}% <<< 7cm to see the difference
\draw[fill=teal!20] (#1,#2)--(#1+0.5*#3,#2+0.86*#3)--(#1+1*#3,#2)--cycle;%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\trnglB}[3]{%
\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw[fill=yellow!20] (#1,#2)--(#1+0.5*#3,#2+0.86*#3)--(#1+1*#3,#2)--cycle;%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
\normalsize
% ~~~ variations of your code: WATCH the differences ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Here is my text and the \textbf{triangle} on same line \trngl{10}{0}{3}

Here is my text and the \textbf{triangle} still on same line
\trngl{10}{0}{3}


Here is my text and the \textbf{triangle} on next line

\trngl{10}{0}{3}

% ~~~ using some (hopefully correct) \hspace{} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Here is my text and the \textbf{triangleA} on next line

\trnglA{10}{0}{3}

% ~~~ using \hfill ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Here is my text and the \textbf{triangleB} on next line

\trnglB{10}{0}{3}

\end{document}


I understood everything, thanks for showing everything you can do with \newcommand and tikzpicture, you answered my question :D

Fine :) Succesful latexing.
